# Button not showing in Plone, onclick also not working

Tags: javascript, html, plone

I am editing a plone page to open an Excel document on a specific sheet. I created two buttons to see if either would appear as actual buttons and use the JS function I reference. With this code the exact part of the page looks like the image below.

[image: Button View]

Why is only text showing instead of the button and why is the onclick attribute not working?

Note: I have changed to links to the spreadsheet for posting it on here but the link has been tested on other webpages

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Open_Excel_File(path,sheet)
      {

        fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

        if (!fso.FileExists(path))
          alert("Cannot open file.\nFile '" + path + "' doesn't exist.");

        else
         {
           var myApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

           if (myApp != null)
             {
               myApp.visible = true;
               Book = myApp.workbooks.open(path);
               var excel_sheet = Book.Worksheets(sheet).Activate;
               myApp.range(f_range).Select;
             }

           else {
             alert ("Cannot open Excel application");
           }
         }
      }
 </script>


<div>
<button onclick='Open_Excel_File("file://///fs-01\Departments\Underwriting\Statistical%20Data%20and%20Medical%20Information\Statistics\Cancers\Cancer%20Statistics%\Cancer%20Statistics%.xlsx", "Vulvar Ca");'>Open File</button>
<input type="button" onclick="Open_Excel_File('file://///fs-01\deps\uw\stat%20Data%20and%20Medical%20Information\Statistics\Cancers\Cancer%20Statistics%202018\Cancer%20Statistics%.xlsx', 'VCA');'>OPEN FILE</input>
</div>
```

Comment: which phone? android or iphone?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Plone the CMS

Comment: So what is your question? There is no question.

Comment: @BryanElliott I have just updated my post to include a direct question.

Comment: @O'Cheezy - `input` is an self-closing tag. use `value` attribute to display button label.

Answer (score 0):

1. your onclick value is not a function, it is the result of a function call. Try to change that to `onclick="Open_Excel_File"`; You'll have to provide the file path at some point
2. Accessing file system from browser is super restricted for security matters, the only way I see fit is to have a file input and using what user provides

Answer (score 0):

Also Plone filter out a bounce of potential "nasty" tags through a specific configurable tool.
It seems to me that you have injected the   in the source HTML of a Page (document) type.

If so, you will see in your browser that in, the page source code, the script tag has been totally stripped away.

So,
a correct way to inject some js in your page, is to load it as portal_javascript resource (plone<=4) or in resource_registry (plone>=5).

tha nasty way is to access, in the ZMI, at `https://yourseite:8080/Plone/portal_transforms/safe_html/` and configure it to accept script tags inside a document (all document in your site actually).

If this answer does not satisfy you try to ask in the official community:
http://community.plone.org

hth,
alessandro